# Logcat refreshes when app restarts after crashing in an activity in Android. How to preserve it?

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

I am building an android app. I get some exception thrown during an activity and as a result, the app crashes. Before I could see and debug the exception in Logcat, it refreshes the log as the app restarts. So I am not able to find the cause of the exception. How to preserve the log as it is so that I can fully what has happened?.

Comment: do not click on ok when app crashes

Comment: It doesn't prompt me saying app is not responding with ok button

Comment: aint you getting the error message saying **unfortunately your app has stopped working** ?

Comment: I am not getting that message. It will just quickly restart :/